# Convert Pandas column containing NaNs to dtype `int`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, dtype

I read data from a .csv file to a Pandas dataframe as below. For one of the columns, namely `id`, I want to specify the column type as `int`. The problem is the `id` series has missing/empty values.

When I try to cast the `id` column to integer while reading the .csv, I get:

```
df= pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={'id': int}) 
error: Integer column has NA values
```

Alternatively, I tried to convert the column type after reading as below, but this time I get:

```
df= pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
df[['id']] = df[['id']].astype(int)
error: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Could you post the content of your file?

Comment: @xndrme, the file itself is too large. I will see if I can create a small test case. But essentially the situation is that the `id` column has many integer values and some empty/missing cells.

Comment: I think that integer values cannot be converted or stored in a series/dataframe if there are missing/NaN values. This I think is to do with numpy compatibility (I'm guessing here), if you want missing value compatibility then I would store the values as floats

Comment: see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions; you must have a float dtype when u have missing values (or technically object dtype but that is inefficient); what is your goal of using int type?

Comment: FYI, if you don't specify a dtype, then pandas will infer float for the column, no conversion needed.

Comment: I believe this is a NumPy issue, not specific to Pandas. It's a shame since there are so many cases when having an int type that allows for the possibility of null values is much more efficient than a large column of floats.

Comment: I have a problem with this too. I have multiple dataframes which I want to merge based on a string representation of several "integer" columns. However, when one of those integer columns has a np.nan, the string casting produces a ".0", which throws off the merge. Just makes things slightly more complicated, would be nice if there was simple work-around.

Comment: @Rhubarb, Optional Nullable Integer Support is now officially added on pandas 0.24.0 - finally :) - please find an updated answer bellow. [pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The lack of NaN rep in integer columns is a [pandas "gotcha"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).

The usual workaround is to simply use floats.

Comment: Are there any other workarounds besides treating them like floats?

Comment: @jsc123 you can use the object dtype. This comes with a small health warning but for the most part works well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use object dtype?  I've been looking through the pandas docs and googling, and I've read it's the recommended method.  But, I haven't found an example of how to use the object dtype.

Comment: In v0.24, you can now do `df = df.astype(pd.Int32Dtype())` (to convert the entire dataFrame, or) `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(pd.Int32Dtype())`. Other accepted nullable integer types are `pd.Int16Dtype` and `pd.Int64Dtype`. Pick your poison.

Comment: It is NaN value but isnan checking doesn't work at all :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029359/pandas-convert-column-to-int-and-coerce-nan

Comment: @cs95 I am getting erro `object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype`

Comment: Another workaround is to use strings for everything (won't be as efficient)

Answer (score 353):

In version 0.24.+ pandas has gained the ability to hold integer dtypes with missing values.

[Nullable Integer Data Type](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Pandas can represent integer data with possibly missing values using [`arrays.IntegerArray`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html). This is an extension types implemented within pandas. It is not the default dtype for integers, and will not be inferred; you must explicitly pass the dtype into [`array()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.array.html#pandas.array) or `Series`:

```
arr = pd.array([1, 2, np.nan], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
pd.Series(arr)

0      1
1      2
2    NaN
dtype: Int64
```

For convert column to nullable integers use:

```
df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].astype('Int64')
```

Comment: Note that dtype must be `"Int64"` and not `"int64"` (first 'i' must be capitalized)

Comment: `df.myCol = df.myCol.astype('Int64')` or `df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].astype('Int64')`

Comment: It may be obvious to some but it I think it is still worth noting that you can use any Int (e.g. `Int16`, `Int32`) and indeed probably should if the dataframe is very large to save memory.

Comment: @jezrael, in which cases this does not work...? It does not work for me and I have failed to find a generic solution.

Comment: @Newbielp - First idea is test if `nan` are missing values or strings `'nan'`

Comment: @jezrael, it gives me type float for specific element. Whole column is type object.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64`

Comment: @Zhubarb please consider changing your accepted answer in light of this development

Comment: As of pandas 1.4, IntegerArray and `pandas.NA` are still marked as **experimental**

Comment: Use `dtype` argument  as `Int64` and not as `np.int64` or `int64`

Answer (score 79):

My use case is munging data prior to loading into a DB table:

```
df[col] = df[col].fillna(-1)
df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
df[col] = df[col].replace('-1', np.nan)
```

Remove NaNs, convert to int, convert to str and then reinsert NANs.

It's not pretty but it gets the job done!

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out trying to load serial numbers where some are null and the rest are floats, this saved me.

Comment: The OP wants a column of integers. Converting it to string does not meet the condition.

Comment: Works only if col doesn't already have -1. Otherwise, it will mess with the data

Comment: then how to get back to int..??

Comment: This produces a column of strings!! For a solution with current versions of `pandas`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029359/pandas-convert-column-to-int-and-coerce-nan

Comment: Use case here for this answer is trying to load to a DB - so potentially writing to csv then bulk insert - in this case, forcing the int to string then writing it stops SQL complaining that e.g. 10.0 is not an int and can't be loaded. But not a solution for all cases.

Answer (score 15):

Whether your pandas series is `object` datatype or simply `float` datatype the below method will work

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(float).astype('Int64')
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Bhatia this worked for me.

Comment: This is one of the better answers on this thread.

Answer (score 13):

It is now possible to create a pandas column containing NaNs as dtype `int`, since it is now officially added on pandas 0.24.0

[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)
Quote: "**Pandas has gained the ability to hold integer dtypes with missing values**

Answer (score 7):

As of Pandas 1.0.0 you can now use pandas.NA values. This does not force integer columns with missing values to be floats.

When reading in your data all you have to do is:

```
df= pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={'id': 'Int64'})
```

Notice the 'Int64' is surrounded by quotes and the I is capitalized. This distinguishes Panda's 'Int64' from numpy's int64.

As a side note, this will also work with .astype()

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype('Int64')
```

You might have to use round if you actually have floats.

```
df['id'] = df['id'].round().astype('Int64')
```

Documentation here
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Answer (score 7):

I had the problem a few weeks ago with a few discrete features which were formatted as 'object'. This solution seemed to work.

```
for col in discrete:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='coerce').astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Answer (score 6):

If you absolutely want to combine integers and NaNs in a column, you can use the 'object' data type:

```
df['col'] = (
    df['col'].fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .astype(object)
    .where(df['col'].notnull())
)
```

This will replace NaNs with an integer (doesn't matter which), convert to int, convert to object and finally reinsert NaNs.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.dropna()` if it is OK to drop the rows with the NaN values.

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['id'])
```

Alternatively,
use `.fillna()` and `.astype()` to replace the NaN with values and convert them to int.

I ran into this problem when processing a CSV file with large integers, while some of them were missing (NaN). Using float as the type was not an option, because I might loose the precision.

My solution was to **use str as the intermediate type**. 
Then you can convert the string to int as you please later in the code. I replaced NaN with 0, but you could choose any value.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype={'id':str})
df["id"] = df["id"].fillna("0").astype(int)
```

For the illustration, here is an example how floats may loose the precision:

```
s = "12345678901234567890"
f = float(s)
i = int(f)
i2 = int(s)
print (f, i, i2)
```

And the output is:

```
1.2345678901234567e+19 12345678901234567168 12345678901234567890
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify your stored data, use a sentinel value for missing `id`. A common use case, inferred by the column name,  being that `id` is an integer, strictly greater than zero, you could use `0` as a sentinel value so that you can write

```
if row['id']:
   regular_process(row)
else:
   special_process(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most solutions here tell you how to use a placeholder integer to represent nulls. That approach isn't helpful if you're uncertain that integer won't show up in your source data though. My method with will format floats without their decimal values and convert nulls to None's. The result is an object datatype that will look like an integer field with null values when loaded into a CSV.

```
keep_df[col] = keep_df[col].apply(lambda x: None if pandas.isnull(x) else '{0:.0f}'.format(pandas.to_numeric(x)))
```

Comment: this approach can add a lot of memory overhead, especially on larger dataframes

Answer (score 3):

The issue with `Int64`, like many other's solutions, is that if you have `null` values, they get replaced with `<NA>` values, which do not work with pandas default 'NaN' functions, like `isnull()` or `fillna()`. Or if you convert values to `-1` you end up in a situation where you may be deleting your information. My solution is a little lame, but will provide `int` values with `np.nan`, allowing for `nan` functions to work without compromising your values.

```
            def to_int(x):
                try:
                    return int(x)
                except:
                    return np.nan

            df[column] = df[column].apply(to_int)
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone needing to have int values within NULL/NaN-containing columns, but working under the constraint of being unable to use pandas version 0.24.0 nullable integer features mentioned in other answers, I suggest converting the columns to object type using pd.where:

```
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

This converts all NaNs in the dataframe to None, treating mixed-type columns as objects, but leaving the int values as int, rather than float.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['id'] = pd.to_numeric(df['id'])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer this formulation over that proposed in the accepted answer? If so, it'd be useful to edit your answer to provide that explanation—and especially since there are ten _additional_ answers that are competing for attention.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how/why your code addresses it. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform differentiates it from forums. You can `edit` to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it when you chain methods, you can use assign:

```
df = (
     df.assign(col = lambda x: x['col'].astype('Int64'))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to specify the newer integer type, Int8 (...Int64) that can handle null integer data (pandas version >= 0.24.0)

`df = df.astype('Int8')`

But you may want to only target specific columns which have integer data mixed with NaN/nulls:

`df = df.astype({'col1':'Int8','col2':'Int8','col3':'Int8')`

At this point, the NaN's are converted into `<NA>` and if you want to change the default null value with df.fillna(), you need to coerce the object datatype on the columns you wish to change, otherwise you will see
`TypeError: <U1 cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype`

You can do this by
`df = df.astype(object)` if you don't mind changing every column datatype to object (individually, each value's type is still preserved) ... OR
`df = df.astype({"col1": object,"col2": object})` if you prefer to target individual columns.

This should help with forcing your integer columns mixed with nulls to stay formatted as integers and change the null values to whatever you like. I can't speak to the efficiency of this method, but it worked for my formatting and printing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue working with pyspark. As this is a python frontend for code running on a jvm, it requires type safety and using float instead of int is not an option. I worked around the issue by wrapping the pandas `pd.read_csv` in a function that will fill user-defined columns with user-defined fill values before casting them to the required type. Here is what I ended up using:

```
def custom_read_csv(file_path, custom_dtype = None, fill_values = None, **kwargs):
    if custom_dtype is None:
        return pd.read_csv(file_path, **kwargs)
    else:
        assert 'dtype' not in kwargs.keys()
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, dtype = {}, **kwargs)
        for col, typ in custom_dtype.items():
            if fill_values is None or col not in fill_values.keys():
                fill_val = -1
            else:
                fill_val = fill_values[col]
            df[col] = df[col].fillna(fill_val).astype(typ)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`df[['id']] = df[['id']].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`

If you print it's  `dtypes`, you will get  `id       Int64` instead of normal  `one       int64`

Answer (score 1):

df['id'] = df['id'].astype('float').astype(pd.Int64Dtype())

Answer (score 0):

First remove the rows which contain NaN. Then do Integer conversion on remaining rows.
At Last insert the removed rows again.
Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use `.fillna()` to replace all `NaN` values with `0` and then convert it to `int` using `astype(int)`

```
df['id'] = df['id'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Works but I think replacing NaN with 0 changes the meaning of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. That was my solution:

```
def toint(zahl = 1.1):
    try:
        zahl = int(zahl)
    except:
        zahl = np.nan
    return zahl

print(toint(4.776655), toint(np.nan), toint('test'))
```

> 4 nan nan

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(float)
df['id'] = toint(df['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach of [@Digestible1010101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int/67929601#67929601) is the more appropriate for Pandas 1.2.+ versions, something like this should do the job:

```
df = df.astype({
            'col_1': 'Int64',
            'col_2': 'Int64',
            'col_3': 'Int64',
            'col_4': 'Int64', })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't see the answer here, I might as well add it:

One-liner to convert NANs to empty string if you for some reason you still can't handle np.na or pd.NA like me when relying on a library with an older version of pandas:

`df.select_dtypes('number').fillna(-1).astype(str).replace('-1', '')`

Comment: caution with this approach... if any of your data really is -1, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @hibernado's answer, but keeping it as integers (instead of strings)

```
df[col] = df[col].fillna(-1)
df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
df[col] = np.where(df[col] == -1, np.nan, df[col])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.loc[~df['id'].isna(), 'id'] = df.loc[~df['id'].isna(), 'id'].astype('int')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following workaround:

```
condition = (~df['mixed_column'].isnull())
df['mixed_column'] = df['mixed_column'].mask(condition, df[condition]['mixed_column'].astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround at file read, assuming you don't need any integer operations other than equality, is to not infer dtype and import everything as strings. This is less efficient but simple and closer to what is actually in CSV files, since CSV files don't have any notion of type.

```
pd.read_csv(path, dtype=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try:

```
df.id = df.id.astype(int, errors = 'ignore')
```

There can be any numeric type instead of **int**.

Comment: This unfortunately won't work. According to [the docs on `astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), the `'ignore'` flag will return the original object on error. So if there are `NaN` values, there is an error, and nothing will be changed.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your DateColumn formatted 3312018.0 should be converted to 03/31/2018 as a string.  And, some records are missing or 0.

```
df['DateColumn'] = df['DateColumn'].astype(int)
df['DateColumn'] = df['DateColumn'].astype(str)
df['DateColumn'] = df['DateColumn'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(8))
df.loc[df['DateColumn'] == '00000000','DateColumn'] = '01011980'
df['DateColumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateColumn'], format="%m%d%Y")
df['DateColumn'] = df['DateColumn'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Answer (score -2):

use pd.to_numeric()

```
df["DateColumn"] = pd.to_numeric(df["DateColumn"])
```

simple and clean

Comment: If there are NaN values in the column, pd.to_numeric will convert the dtype to float not int because NaN is considered a float.