# Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've read an SQL query into Pandas and the values are coming in as dtype 'object', although they are strings, dates and integers. I am able to convert the date 'object' to a Pandas datetime dtype, but I'm getting an error when trying to convert the string and integers.

Here is an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from my_table', conn)
>>> df
    id    date          purchase
 1  abc1  2016-05-22    1
 2  abc2  2016-05-29    0
 3  abc3  2016-05-22    2
 4  abc4  2016-05-22    0

>>> df.dtypes
 id          object
 date        object
 purchase    object
 dtype: object
```

Converting the `df['date']` to a datetime works:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
 1  2016-05-22
 2  2016-05-29
 3  2016-05-22
 4  2016-05-22
 Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But I get an error when trying to convert the `df['purchase']` to an integer:

```
>>> df['purchase'].astype(int)
 ....
 pandas/lib.pyx in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:16667)()
 pandas/src/util.pxd in util.set_value_at (pandas/lib.c:67540)()

 TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'java.lang.Long'
```

NOTE: I get a similar error when I tried `.astype('float')`

And when trying to convert to a string, nothing seems to happen.

```
>>> df['id'].apply(str)
 1 abc1
 2 abc2
 3 abc3
 4 abc4
 Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm guessing, try `df['purchase'].astype(str).astype(int)`

Comment: There is no string dtype. It stays as object. For the other one, try the more general `pd.to_numeric(df['purchase'])` then you can add `.astype(int)` if that is successful.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Documenting the answer that worked for me based on the comment by @piRSquared.

I needed to convert to a string first, then an integer.

```
>>> df['purchase'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.0'` huh?

Answer (score 35):

### pandas >= 1.0

## [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes)

The (self) accepted answer doesn't take into consideration the possibility of NaNs in object columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'a': [1, 2, np.nan], 
     'b': [True, False, np.nan]}, dtype=object) 
df                                                                         

     a      b
0    1   True
1    2  False
2  NaN    NaN

df['a'].astype(str).astype(int) # raises ValueError
```

This chokes because the NaN is converted to a string "nan", and further attempts to coerce to integer will fail. To avoid this issue, we can soft-convert columns to their corresponding [nullable type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) using `convert_dtypes`:

```
df.convert_dtypes()                                                        

      a      b
0     1   True
1     2  False
2  <NA>   <NA>

df.convert_dtypes().dtypes                                                 

a      Int64
b    boolean
dtype: object
```

If your data has junk text mixed in with your ints, you can use `pd.to_numeric` as an initial step:

```
s = pd.Series(['1', '2', '...'])
s.convert_dtypes()  # converts to string, which is not what we want

0      1
1      2
2    ...
dtype: string 

# coerces non-numeric junk to NaNs
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64

# one final `convert_dtypes` call to convert to nullable int
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').convert_dtypes() 

0       1
1       2
2    <NA>
dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 15):

```
df['col_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col_name'])
```

This is a better option

Comment: Could you explain on why it is better?

Answer (score 6):

My train data contains three features are object after applying `astype` it converts the object into numeric but before that, you need to perform some preprocessing steps:

```
train.dtypes

C12       object
C13       object
C14       Object

train['C14'] = train.C14.astype(int)

train.dtypes

C12       object
C13       object
C14       int32
```

Answer (score 5):

It's simple

```py
pd.factorize(df.purchase)[0]
```

Example:

```
labels, uniques = pd.factorize(['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'])`
```

```py
labels
# array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0])
```

```py
uniques
# array(['b', 'a', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Huh?! some more commenting could make this really clearer

Comment: not sure why it gets two downvotes. It seems to apply more generalized cases. works for me

Comment: This is a conversion problem, not a factorization one, perhaps that's why @FlowingCloud

Answer (score 5):

to change the data type and save it into the data frame, it is needed to replace the new data type as follows:

```
ds["cat"] = pd.to_numeric(ds["cat"])
```

or

```
ds["cat"] = ds["cat"].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1.clean your file -> open your datafile in `csv` format and see that there is "?" in place of empty places and delete all of them.

2.drop the rows containing missing values
e.g.:

```
df.dropna(subset=["normalized-losses"], axis = 0 , inplace= True)
```

3.use astype now for conversion

```
df["normalized-losses"]=df["normalized-losses"].astype(int)
```

Note: If still finding erros in your program then again inspect your `csv` file, open it in excel to find whether is there an "?" in your required column, then delete it and save file and go back and run your program.

comment success! if it works. :)

Comment: Not all files can be opened in Excel for such checking.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot comment so posting this as an answer, which is somewhat in between [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int#comment65689890_39173813)/[@cyril](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216001/11896053)'s solution and [@cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60203797/11896053)'s:

As noted by @cs95, if your data contains NaNs or Nones, converting to string type will throw an error when trying to convert to int afterwards.

However, if your data consists of (numerical) strings, using `convert_dtypes` will convert it to string type unless you use `pd.to_numeric` as suggested by @cs95 (potentially combined with `df.apply()`).

In the case that your data consists only of numerical strings (including NaNs or Nones but without any non-numeric "junk"), a possibly simpler alternative would be to convert first to float and then to one of the [nullable-integer extension dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) provided by pandas (already present in version 0.24) (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194908/11896053)):

```
df['purchase'].astype(float).astype('Int64')
```

Note that there has been recent discussion on this on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28599) (currently an -unresolved- closed issue though) and that in the case of very long 64-bit integers you may have to convert explicitly to `float128` to avoid approximations during the conversions.

Answer (score 1):

If these methods fail, you can try a list comprehension such as this:

```
df["int_column"] = [int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in df["str_column"] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a df with mixed data:

```
df:
                     0   1   2    ...                  242                  243                  244
0   2020-04-22T04:00:00Z   0   0  ...          3,094,409.5         13,220,425.7          5,449,201.1
1   2020-04-22T06:00:00Z   0   0  ...          3,716,941.5          8,452,012.9          6,541,599.9
....
```

The floats are actually objects, but I need them to be real floats.

To fix it, referencing @AMC's comment above:

```
def coerce_to_float(val):
    try:
       return float(val)
    except ValueError:
       return val

df = df.applymap(lambda x: coerce_to_float(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting object to numerical `int` or `float`.

code is:--

```py
df["total_sqft"] = pd.to_numeric(df["total_sqft"], errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Answer (score -1):

use astype fuction to convert the datype of that column

Comment: This was already suggested [in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216001/18145256)!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

[This was my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0CGT.png)

```
## list of columns 
l1 = ['PM2.5', 'PM10', 'TEMP', 'BP', ' RH', 'WS','CO', 'O3', 'Nox', 'SO2'] 

for i in l1:
 for j in range(0, 8431): #rows = 8431
   df[i][j] = int(df[i][j])
```

I recommend you to use this only with small data. This code has complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: This solutions seems inferior to many of the existing ones, why choose this?

Comment: .astype() method was not working in my code. So I converted each item to integer using int() func

Comment: _.astype() method was not working in my code._ Can you be more specific? _So I converted each item to integer using int() func_ If that is necessary, then you should use `Series.map()` or `DataFrame.applymap()`.