# Converting object to Int pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have an issue to convert column of object to integer for complete column.

I have a data frame and I tried to convert some columns that are detected as Object into Integer (or Float) but all the answers I already found are working for me

[First status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo9cf.png)

Then I tried to apply the to_numeric method but doesn't work.
[To numeric method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HIuX.png)

Then a custom method that you can find here: [Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)
but doesn't work either: `data3['Title'].astype(str).astype(int)`
( I cannot pass the image anymore - You have to trust me that it doesn't work)

I tried to use the inplace statement but doesn't seem to be integrated in those methods:

I am pretty sure that the answer is dumb but cannot find it

Comment: You need to self-assign e.g. `data3['Title'] = pd.to_numeric(data3['Title'])` or `data3['Title'] data3['Title'].astype(int)` There really should be a canonical question for this as this variant appears umpteen times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need assign output back:

```
#maybe also works omit astype(str)
data3['Title'] = data3['Title'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
data3['Title'] = pd.to_numeric(data3['Title'])
```

Sample:

```
data3 = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['15','12','10']})
print (data3)
  Title
0    15
1    12
2    10

print (data3.dtypes)
Title    object
dtype: object
```

---

```
data3['Title'] = pd.to_numeric(data3['Title'])
print (data3.dtypes)
Title    int64
dtype: object
```

---

```
data3['Title'] = data3['Title'].astype(int)

print (data3.dtypes)
Title    int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

As python_enthusiast said ,

This command works for me too

```
data3.Title = data3.Title.str.replace(',', '').astype(float).astype(int)
```

but also works fine with

```
data3.Title = data3.Title.str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

you have to use str before replace in order to get rid of commas only then change it to int/float other wise you will get error .

Answer (score 2):

2 years and 11 months later, but here I go.

It's important to check if your data has any spaces, special characters (like commas, dots, or whatever else) first. If yes, then you need to basically remove those and then convert your string data into float and then into an integer (this is what worked for me for the case where my data was numerical values but with commas, like 4,118,662).

```
data3.Title = data3.Title.str.replace(',', '').astype(flaoat).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can try this code, work fine with me

```
data3.Title= pd.factorize(data3.Title)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a dataset like this

```
dataset.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 79902 entries, 0 to 79901
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   Query             79902 non-null  object
 1   Video Title       79902 non-null  object
 2   Video ID          79902 non-null  object
 3   Video Views       79902 non-null  object
 4   Comment ID        79902 non-null  object
 5   cleaned_comments  79902 non-null  object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 5.5+ MB
```

Removed the None, NaN entries using

```
dataset = dataset.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 79868 entries, 0 to 79901
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   Query             79868 non-null  object
 1   Video Title       79868 non-null  object
 2   Video ID          79868 non-null  object
 3   Video Views       79868 non-null  object
 4   Comment ID        79868 non-null  object
 5   cleaned_comments  79868 non-null  object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 6.1+ MB
```

Notice the reduced entries

But the `Video Views` were floats, as shown in `dataset.head()`

Then I used

```
dataset['Video Views'] = pd.to_numeric(dataset['Video Views'])
dataset['Video Views'] = dataset['Video Views'].astype(int)
```

Now,

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 79868 entries, 0 to 79901
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   Query             79868 non-null  object
 1   Video Title       79868 non-null  object
 2   Video ID          79868 non-null  object
 3   Video Views       79868 non-null  int64 
 4   Comment ID        79868 non-null  object
 5   cleaned_comments  79868 non-null  object
dtypes: int64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 6.1+ MB
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Version that works with Nulls

With older version of Pandas there was no `NaN` for `int` but newer versions of pandas offer `Int64` which has `pd.NA`.

So to go from `object` to `int` with missing data you can do this.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('Int64')
```

By switching to float first you avoid `object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype` error.

Note it is capital 'I' in the `Int64`.

More info here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

#### Working with pd.NA

In Pandas 1.0 the new pd.NA datatype has been introduced; the goal of pd.NA is to provide a “missing” indicator that can be used consistently across data types (instead of np.nan, None or pd.NaT depending on the data type).

With this in mind they have created the `dataframe.convert_dtypes()` and `Series.convert_dtypes()` functions which converts to datatypes that support pd.NA. This is currently considered experimental but might well be a bright future.