# How to convert numeric strings with period separators to float?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the values in a Pandas DataFrame from string to float but am running into an error.

The column looks like this:

```
PIB (IBGE/2005)
---------------
 71.638.000
114.250.000
 44.373.000
462.258.000
186.812.000
```

Where the `.` are the digit group separators, so `71.638.000` should become the float `71638000`.

But I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '71.638.000'
```

Here is an image of my full DataFrame:

[image: Dataframe screenshot]
How can I convert this column from string to float?

Comment: What is `71.638.000` supposed to be as a float?

Comment: It looks like that the character `.` in your dataset is a thousand separator, which confuses your parsing library (probably set by default to understand `.` as the English decimal point). I'd recommend  cleaning your data to remove those `.`

Comment: @Pac0 maybe the problem is really the thousand separator, I'll check that out. thank you

Comment: use `pd.read_csv(yourfile, thousands='.')` or `pd.to_numeric(df[column])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)

Comment: It worked, the problem was really the period as a thousands separator ... thank you very much to everyone who contributed

Answer (score 1):

The values in column 'PIB (IBGE/2005)' appear to have a period as thousands separators. You'll have to remove those before converting the values to floats. You could try something along these lines to prepare the column for conversion to float:

```
df1 = df1['PIB (IBGE/2005)'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.', ''))
```

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments below as a more **proper** solution to [avoid apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

```
df1 = df1['PIB (IBGE/2005)'].str.replace('.', '')
```

Comment: Or use one of pandas' string methods for that: df1 = df1['PIB (IBGE/2005)'].str.replace('.', '')

Comment: don't use [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) when you have methods can you use in its place.

Comment: It worked, the problem was really the period as a thousands separator ... thank you very much to everyone who contributed

Answer (score 0):

Replace '.' with '' and convert string into float

```
S = "123.567.000"
D = float(S.replace('.',''))
print(D)
```