# Replacing a specific column with mean values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace the user_score with the average user_score for the game's platform and genre.
This is my code:

```
dft = new_df.query('user_score != "tbd" & user_score.isnull()')
df_typical_user_ratio_by_platform = dft.groupby(['platform', 'genre'])['user_score'].apply(lambda x: x.sample(1).iloc[0])

def correct_user_score(row):
    platform = row['platform']
    genre = row['genre']
    if (row['user_score'] == 'tbd' or pd.isnull(row['user_score']) or row['user_score']=='nan'):
        u = df_typical_user_ratio_by_platform.loc[[platform, genre]].head(1).astype('float')
        uScore = ", ".join(map(str, u)) 
    else:
        uScore = row['user_score']
        
    return uScore

row = pd.Series(data=row_values, index=['user_score', 'platform', 'genre'])
correct_user_score(row)
new_df['user_score'] = new_df.apply(correct_user_score, axis=1)
new_df.sample(40)
# df['user_score'] = df['user_score'].astype('int')
```

This is the result. user_score is currently an object. I'm not sure how to replace nan. I tried doing if u = 'nan', but that didn't work. Any advice?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7AU4.jpg

Comment: Here are some ways to replace nan: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-nan-values-with-zeros-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: right, but it's an object and 'nan'

Comment: Your image shows "NaN", which is of course not equal to "nan".  Are you actually getting the string "NaN", or are you getting the floating point value NaN?  Those are also two different things.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60203797/11380795) solution

Comment: sample data and sample output,  the whole approach looks more complex than needed

Comment: Hi so I'm trying to fix the 'user_score' column only right now and it does have object 'nan' in it which is different from 'NaN'. @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

- force invalid values to **NaN** with `to_numerice()`
- `fillna()` with calculation you want

```
s = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({"userid":np.random.randint(1,5,s),
             "platform":np.random.choice(["windows","macos","ios","android"],s),
             "userscore":np.random.randint(1,10,s)})

# let's splat some scores...
df = df.assign(userscore=np.select([(df.userscore==7)&(df.index<10),(df.userscore==6)&(df.index<10)],["tbd",np.nan],df.userscore))

df["bad"] = df.userscore
df = df.assign(userscore=pd.to_numeric(df.userscore, errors="coerce"))
df.userscore = df.userscore.fillna(df.groupby(["userid","platform"])["userscore"].transform("mean"))
```

#### output

|  | userid | platform | userscore | bad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | ios | 8 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | ios | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | macos | 4.5 | tbd |
| 3 | 2 | macos | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | android | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | ios | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 | macos | 5 | 5 |
| 7 | 4 | android | 8 | nan |
| 8 | 1 | macos | 4 | 4 |
| 9 | 2 | windows | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 | android | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 4 | windows | 5 | 5 |
| 12 | 3 | android | 2 | 2 |
| 13 | 2 | windows | 9 | 9 |
| 14 | 3 | android | 8 | 8 |
| 15 | 2 | windows | 1 | 1 |
| 16 | 4 | windows | 8 | 8 |
| 17 | 2 | windows | 4 | 4 |
| 18 | 2 | ios | 3 | 3 |
| 19 | 4 | android | 8 | 8 |