# Converting football score to a number in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion, numbers

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to do some calcualtions on footbal scores Data frame.
Is there a way to convert football scores (eg.3-2, 2-0..) from object dtype to a number, so I can perform some numerical operations on them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you provide sample code, expected input and output?

Comment: Are they stored in string form, i.e. `"3-2"` ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int#39216001

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I didn't explain well enough. So I have a column with results stored in string form (i.e. "2-4", "1-1"..)  from all the matches in the season and now I would like to sum all the goals in the season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, provide a sample dataset with expected input and output.

You can split the column on the `'-'` charachter. Convert the columns to int and do a groupby to sum the point totals.

**Given:**

```
print(df)
  Team Result Score
0    A      W   3-0
1    A      W   3-2
2    A      L   2-4
3    A      L   1-2
4    B      W   1-0
5    B      L   0-1
6    B      T   1-1
7    B      L   2-3
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([['A','W','3-0'],
                   ['A','W','3-2'],
                   ['A','L','2-4'],
                   ['A','L','1-2'],
                   ['B','W','1-0'],
                   ['B','L','0-1'],
                   ['B','T','1-1'],
                   ['B','L','2-3']], columns=['Team','Result','Score'])

df[['Team Points','Opp Points']] = df['Score'].str.split('-',expand=True)
df[['Team Points','Opp Points']] = df[['Team Points','Opp Points']].astype(int)

df_sum = df.groupby(['Team'])['Team Points'].sum()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
  Team Result Score  Team Points  Opp Points
0    A      W   3-0            3           0
1    A      W   3-2            3           2
2    A      L   2-4            2           4
3    A      L   1-2            1           2
4    B      W   1-0            1           0
5    B      L   0-1            0           1
6    B      T   1-1            1           1
7    B      L   2-3            2           3
```

**Sum:**

```
print(df_sum)
Team
A    9
B    4
Name: Team Points, dtype: int32
```