# Convert datetime64 to integer hours using Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, integer

I have the following dataframe

```
        Timestamp           KE          EH  LA       PR
0       2013-02-27 00:00:00 1.000000    2.0 0.03    201.289993
1       2013-02-27 00:15:00 0.990000    2.0 0.03    210.070007
2       2013-02-27 00:30:00 0.950000    2.0 0.02    207.779999
3       2013-02-27 00:45:00 0.990000    2.0 0.03    151.960007
4       2013-02-27 01:00:00 341.209991  2.0 0.04    0.000000
... ... ... ... ... ...
3449    2013-04-03 22:15:00 NaN         2.0 0.03    0.000000
3450    2013-04-03 22:30:00 NaN         NaN 0.07    0.000000
```

I would like to turn the timestamp column into a numeric value while keeping only the 'time' like illustrated below

```
        Timestamp           KE          EH  LA       PR
0       0                   1.000000    2.0 0.03    201.289993
1       15                  0.990000    2.0 0.03    210.070007
2       30                  0.950000    2.0 0.02    207.779999
3       45                  0.990000    2.0 0.03    151.960007
4       100                 341.209991  2.0 0.04    0.000000
... ... ... ... ... ...
3449    2215                NaN         2.0 0.03    0.000000
3450    2230                NaN         NaN 0.07    0.000000
```

I tried the code below based on this post[enter link description here][1]

```
h3_hours["Timestamp"] = h3_hours["Timestamp"].astype(str).astype(int)
```

But this gives me the error below

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2013-02-27 00:00:00'
```

Then I found online this approach

```
# Turn datetime into hours and minutes
h3_hours["Timestamp"] = h3_hours["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%H:%M")

h3_hours["Timestamp"] = h3_hours["Timestamp"].astype(int)
```

But this gives me the same error as above.

Any idea on how I can turn my Timestamp column into integer hours?
[1]: [Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need remove `:` in `%H%M` for `HHMM` format:

```
h3_hours["Timestamp"] = h3_hours["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%H%M").astype(int)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you it worked! Jezrael, thank you for your fast replies always