# Imputation with Sklearn changes 'numerical' columns into 'object' (apart from filling missing data)

Tags: python

Before imputing I had numerical columns in "X_train": numerical_cols = [col for col in X_train.columns if X_train[col].dtype in ['int64','float64']] numerical_cols

After imputing there are no more numerical columns in the new dataframe "imputed_X_train_missing", all the numerical_cols are now 'object'. This is a potential problem when applying XGBRegressor.

This is my code:

````
X_valid_missing = X_valid.copy()

my_imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')

my_imputer.fit(X_train_missing)
imputed_X_train_missing = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(X_train_missing))
imputed_X_valid_missing = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(X_valid_missing))

imputed_X_train_missing.columns = X_train_missing.columns
imputed_X_valid_missing.columns = X_valid_missing.columns ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the imputer when one of the columns is 'object'. After imputation all the columns result 'object':

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

X_train = [['dddd', 2, 3], ['dddd', np.nan, 6], ['dddd', 5, 9]]
X_test = [[np.nan, 2, 3], ['dddd', np.nan, 6], ['dddd', np.nan, 9]]

col_names = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

df_x_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=col_names)
df_x_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test, columns=col_names)
print(df_x_train.info())


RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
# Column Non-Null Count Dtype
--- ------ -------------- -----
0 c1 3 non-null object
1 c2 2 non-null float64
2 c3 3 non-null int64

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
imp.fit(df_x_train)
imputed_x_train = pd.DataFrame(imp.transform(df_x_train))
imputed_x_train.dtypes`

Now all the columns result object:

0 object
1 object
2 object
dtype: object```
````

Answer (score 0):

This may be seen more as treating the symptom instead of the cause, but you could just change the resulting dtypes to a numeric datatype.

Using astype() - [Pandas: convert dtype 'object' to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int)

Using to_numeric() - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I've also stumbled upon this. A bit surprising behaviour.
One of the possible explanations I can see, is that when you use strategy "most_frequent", unlikely you want to use it for continuous features, it's for categories. In any case, if you want to impute only categorical columns and leave numerics unchanged, here is how you can achieve this:

```
categoricals = df.dtypes[
    (df.dtypes == 'object')
].index

df[categoricals] = imputer.fit_transform(df[categoricals])
```