# When to apply(pd.to_numeric) and when to astype(np.float64) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, types

I have a pandas DataFrame object named `xiv` which has a column of `int64` Volume measurements.

```
In[]: xiv['Volume'].head(5)
Out[]: 

0    252000
1    484000
2     62000
3    168000
4    232000
Name: Volume, dtype: int64
```

I have read other posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/pandas-dataframe-column-type-conversion?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)) that suggest the following solutions.  But when I use either approach, it doesn't appear to change the `dtype` of the underlying data:

```
In[]: xiv['Volume'] = pd.to_numeric(xiv['Volume'])

In[]: xiv['Volume'].dtypes
Out[]: 
dtype('int64')
```

Or...

```
In[]: xiv['Volume'] = pd.to_numeric(xiv['Volume'])
Out[]: ###omitted for brevity###

In[]: xiv['Volume'].dtypes
Out[]: 
dtype('int64')

In[]: xiv['Volume'] = xiv['Volume'].apply(pd.to_numeric)

In[]: xiv['Volume'].dtypes
Out[]: 
dtype('int64')
```

I've also tried making a separate pandas `Series` and using the methods listed above on that Series and reassigning to the `x['Volume']` obect, which is a `pandas.core.series.Series` object.

I have, however, found a solution to this problem using the `numpy` package's `float64` type - ***this works but I don't know why it's different***.

```
In[]: xiv['Volume'] = xiv['Volume'].astype(np.float64)

In[]: xiv['Volume'].dtypes
Out[]: 
dtype('float64')
```

Can someone explain how to accomplish with the `pandas` library what the `numpy` library seems to do easily with its `float64` class; that is, convert the column in the `xiv` DataFrame to a `float64` in place.

Comment: `int64` is already "numeric" dtype. `to_numeric()` should help to convert strings into numeric dtypes...

Comment: the cited post shows the `dtype` returned by calling `to_numeric` will be `float64`...

Comment: Check this: `pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(['1','2','3'])).dtype`. It'll be float64 only if it's necessary: 1. there is/are NaN's or non-convertable values in the Series. 2. there are floats in the series

Comment: Understand that this is producing the problem I gave, but how does it address the question of why the numpy solution works instead?

Comment: What is the "problem" and what is/are your goal(s)? BTW pd.Series.astype(np.float64) - is a Pandas method

Comment: @MaxU check my edit at the bottom?

Comment: I've added some demos - I hope it got bit clearer now...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you already have numeric dtypes (`int8|16|32|64`,`float64`,`boolean`) you can convert it to another "numeric" dtype using **Pandas** [.astype()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) method.

Demo:

```
In [90]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10**5,10**7,(5,3)),columns=list('abc'), dtype=np.int64)

In [91]: df
Out[91]:
         a        b        c
0  9059440  9590567  2076918
1  5861102  4566089  1947323
2  6636568   162770  2487991
3  6794572  5236903  5628779
4   470121  4044395  4546794

In [92]: df.dtypes
Out[92]:
a    int64
b    int64
c    int64
dtype: object

In [93]: df['a'] = df['a'].astype(float)

In [94]: df.dtypes
Out[94]:
a    float64
b      int64
c      int64
dtype: object
```

It won't work for `object` (string) dtypes, that **can't** be converted to numbers:

```
In [95]: df.loc[1, 'b'] = 'XXXXXX'

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
           a        b        c
0  9059440.0  9590567  2076918
1  5861102.0   XXXXXX  1947323
2  6636568.0   162770  2487991
3  6794572.0  5236903  5628779
4   470121.0  4044395  4546794

In [97]: df.dtypes
Out[97]:
a    float64
b     object
c      int64
dtype: object

In [98]: df['b'].astype(float)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'XXXXXX'
```

So here we want to use [pd.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method:

```
In [99]: df['b'] = pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce')

In [100]: df
Out[100]:
           a          b        c
0  9059440.0  9590567.0  2076918
1  5861102.0        NaN  1947323
2  6636568.0   162770.0  2487991
3  6794572.0  5236903.0  5628779
4   470121.0  4044395.0  4546794

In [101]: df.dtypes
Out[101]:
a    float64
b    float64
c      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just a Question why did you write df.b, not df['b']?

Comment: @SalmanALharbi: its always better to  use column this format df['column name'] but sometimes if column name doesn't space you can use the column name directly as df.columnname but  df['column name'] should be used always

Comment: @OnlySalman it's just a different and valid syntax. Some people prefer df['column_name] and others prefer df.column_name. With df.column_name the column name must be a valid python syntax. For eg: if column name starts with a number, you can't use dot notation. You can't do df.1, you have to do df[1]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a technical explanation for this but, I have noticed that pd.to_numeric() raises the following error when converting the string 'nan':

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame({'value': 'nan'}, index=[0])

In [11]: pd.to_numeric(df.value)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-98729d13e45c>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_numeric(df.value)

  File "C:\Users\joshua.lee\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 133, in to_numeric
    coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)

  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1185, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric

ValueError: Unable to parse string "nan" at position 0
```

whereas astype(float) does not:

```
df.value.astype(float)
Out[12]: 
0   NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: My guess - it's because this is what python does when we try to convert the string "nan" to a float using float("nan"). The result is a float that represents a quantity that is non a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```py
pd.to_numeric(df.value, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

It will use zero in place of nan.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an explanation that buttresses what the others gave. In summary and as I will show below, `pd.to_numeric(arg, errors='coerce')` can handle numbers that cannot be converted to numeric, such as `'50a'` by converting them to NaN. You can then drop null values. Whereas, `DataFrame.astype()` does not have that ability.

In practice, I use `pd.to_numeric(arg, errors='coerce')` first especially when the DataFrame column or series has the possibility of holding numbers that cannot be converted to Numeric, as it converts those numbers to NaN, I then drop the NaN if desired, then use `DataFrame.astype()` to convert the datatype to the exact numeric data type I desire, such as float64, int32, int64 etc.

`See examples below:`

```
bio = {'Age': [56, 57, '50a'], 'Name': ['YOU', 'ME', 'HIM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(bio)
```

```
>>> df  
Age Name
0   56  YOU
1   57   ME
2  50a  HIM
>>> df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(int)
.......
.......
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '50a'

# Even when the error is forced to be ignore, the change is not made
>>> df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
>>> df
   Age Name
0   56  YOU
1   57   ME
2  50a  HIM
```

### Observe what will happen when I use `pd.to_numeric(arg, errors='coerce')`

```
>>> df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age']) #Used without the coerce
........
........
ValueError: Unable to parse string "50a" at position 2

# When used with parameter: error = coerce, it changes invalid values to Nan. 
# You can then use astype(int) or astype(float) to convert the NaN to 0
>>> df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce')
>>> df
    Age Name
0  56.0  YOU
1  57.0   ME
2   NaN  HIM

# You can then drop nulls if you desire
```

In summary, both work hand in hand for specific purposes especially when handling nulls

Comment: Wonderful! `coerce`, `drop NaN` and then use `astype` . A nasty mal-formed datetime value was driving me crazy. No more!

Answer (score 1):

I observed that I was able to convert object(str) to float first and then float to Int64.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10**5,10**7,(5,3)),columns=list('abc'), 
dtype=np.int64)
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('str')
df.dtypes

df['a'] = df['a'].astype('float')
df['a'] = df['a'].astype('int64')
```

Worked fine.