# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' using Pandas mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I try to get the mean of one of my data frame's columns it shows the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data"

df = pd.read_csv(url, header = None, )

headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration","num-of-doors","body-style","drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base","lenght","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type","num-of-cylinders","engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower","peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]

df.columns = headers

df.replace('?',np.nan, inplace=True)

mean_val = df['normalized-losses'].mean()

print(mean_val)
```

Comment: What's the data type for `df['normalized-losses']`? My guess is it got set to `chr` by default since it had strings (the `"?"`'s) in it and now you have a normal `int + str` error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert the column data type to numeric with `pd.to_numeric()`. If you use the option `errors='coerce'` then it will automatically replace non-numeric characters with `NaN`.

```
mean_val = pd.to_numeric(df['normalized-losses'], errors='coerce').mean()

print(mean_val)

> 122.0
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto Nathaniel's answer, you have a mix of `float` and `str`. You can see this if you

```
print(df['normalized-losses'].apply(type))
```

Which will return

```
0      <class 'float'>
1      <class 'float'>
2      <class 'float'>
3        <class 'str'>
4        <class 'str'>
```

As your error message says, you need to make all of your data of the `float` type. You can either use `pd.to_numeric` as Nathaniel suggested or you can alternatively use

```
df['normalized-losses'] = df['normalized-losses'].astype('float')
mean_val = df['normalized-losses'].mean()
print(mean_val)
```

**Output**

> 122.0

If you are only interested in the normalized-losses column and know that all of your strings can be converted properly (in this case, I believe they can since they are all strings of numbers such as ‘130’), you could just do this. If you are going to use the rest of the data and want to have all numeric strings converted, then use Nathaniel's implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out! That is also a useful approach. [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095712/when-to-applypd-to-numeric-and-when-to-astypenp-float64-in-python) that looks at the differences between pd.to_numeric and df.astype.