# Pandas read_csv dtype=object column contains numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame column with alphanumeric IDs - some numbers, some letters, some both. I am using read_csv to read the data and want to read all the values of this column as strings. I can't change the values in the underlying data.

I have tried to set the dtype for the column as an object

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype = {col: object})
```

I have also tried to use a converter to change all the values in the columns to strings.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, converters = {i: str for i in col})
```

However, I still end up with some non-string numbers (12345) and some string numbers ('12345') which mess up my aggregations.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You may find responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095712/when-to-applypd-to-numeric-and-when-to-astypenp-float64-in-python) helpful.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype = {'col': object}) . I guess you missed the single inverted commas which covers the col. please check it in your code.

Comment: col is a variable with a column name, rather than the name of a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype = {i: str for i in col})
```

The only difference from this and the first one is I do `dtype` not `converter`, it's basically a merge of the two.