# pandas read_sql() avoid conversion to float

Tags: python, sql, pandas

When I perform `pandas.read_sql()`, integer columns that contain NULL values are converted float.

How can I avoid that? I tried `coerce_float=False` but that didn't do it.

[The inability to handle NULL values in integer columns in pandas is REALLY annoying!]

EDIT: I know that pandas can not have NULL values in integer columns. What I would like to achieve is to keep the columns as strings or objects.

Comment: No way yet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290084

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But I would like to at least keep them as strings or objects, and avoid the conversion to floats which has several drawbacks, e.g. losing precision.