# Replacing integers with NaN results in the entire column becoming float dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First, I did

```
a = [[6,5,4,3,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6]]
b = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(b.head(2))
```

The output is

```
1   2   3   4   5      6
6   5   4   3   2.00   NaN
1   2   3   4   5.00   6.00
3   4   5   6   NaN    NaN
```

So I did

```
a = [[6,5,4,3,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6]]
b = pd.DataFrame(a).fillna(-1).astype(int)
print(b.head(2))
```

The output becomes

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
6   5   4   3   2   -1
1   2   3   4   5   6
3   4   5   6   -1  -1
```

But I don't want those -1, so I did

```
a = [[6,5,4,3,2],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6]]
b = pd.DataFrame(a).fillna(-1).astype(int)
b = b.replace(-1, np.NaN)
print(b.head(2))
```

The output is again same as the first time

```
1   2   3   4   5      6
6   5   4   3   2.00   NaN
1   2   3   4   5.00   6.00
3   4   5   6   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int Columns with NaN can't be made int type.

Comment: @Zero there *must* be a better dupe target, but I can't find one atm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this:

```
type(np.nan)
# float
```

If you have `NaN`s in your column, the rest of your column is automatically upcasted to `float` for efficient computation.

### pandas 0.24+

We can use the [Nullable Integer Type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) which allow integers to coexist with NaNs:

```
b = b.astype('Int32')
b

   0  1  2  3    4    5
0  6  5  4  3    2  NaN
1  1  2  3  4    5    6
2  3  4  5  6  NaN  NaN

b.dtypes

0    Int32
1    Int32
2    Int32
3    Int32
4    Int32
5    Int32
dtype: object
```

### <= 0.23

To get around that, convert the `dtype` to `object`, which I don't recommend unless it's only for *display* purposes (you kill efficiency this way).

```
u = df.select_dtypes(float)
b[u.columns] = u.astype(object)
b

   0  1  2  3    4    5
0  6  5  4  3    2  NaN
1  1  2  3  4    5    6
2  3  4  5  6  NaN  NaN

print(b.dtypes)
0     int64
1     int64
2     int64
3     int64
4    object
5    object
dtype: object
```