# pandas inconsistency in concat behavior

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

The following works:

```python
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

as of course it should.  However, the following ought to be exactly the same, and yet it doesn't work:

```python
od3 = OrderedDict([('a', [1]), ('b', [2]), ('c', [3])])
od4 = OrderedDict([('a', []), ('b', []), ('c', [])])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(od3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(od4)
pd.concat([df3, df4])
```

This block of code produces

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 0)
```

Oddly, these all *do* work:

```python
pd.concat([df3.drop_duplicates(), df4.drop_duplicates()])
pd.concat([df3, df4.drop_duplicates()])
pd.concat([df3.drop_duplicates(), df4])
```

although these result in the dataframe having `float64`s instead of `int64`s.

So what's going on?  It seems that Pandas stores `df3` differently from `df1` even though they appear identical, and the `.drop_duplicates()` method converts `df3` to a canonical form.(?)  Any thoughts?

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame([[]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])` gives an error for me: `AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 0 columns`. Maybe specifify which versions you are using...

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.20.3 on Python 3, and can initialize `df2` if I use an empty list for the data. I'm guessing the variables defined as `od3` and `od4` are meant to be `od1` and `od2` respectively, but after making this change, the code runs fine.

Comment: What are  `od1` and `od2`? There are not shown.

Comment: cannot reproduce

Comment: "float64s instead of int64s." because the result has NaN. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290084/1240268

Comment: Ugh, sorry all.  Had a few typos, which have now been fixed.
Specifically, I referred to `od1` and `od2` when I should have referred to `od3` and `od4`, and I had `pd.DataFrame([[]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])` when I should have had `pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])`.  The code above now runs correctly.