# `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'null' ` while converting object to integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, object, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
id   value
1      100
2       50
```

But the value is object not integer or float

```
In[3]:
device_age.dtypes
Out[3]
device_id    object
value        object
dtype: object
```

I want to make it integer `int`, here's what I try:

```
import numpy as np
device_age['value'] = device_age['value'].astype(np.int64)
```

and I also try

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)
```

The error message is

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'null'`

Comment: Your dataframe contains null values. Can you please post the output of `device_age` in your iPython?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I'm already using `df[df['value'] != 'null']` so it not contain null value anymore?

Comment: You are comparing with a `string`