# How to change default data type for exports?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I am working in Databricks. After querying my data via pySql, I want to export the resulting DataFrame. When I do this, it exports 1 out of the many columns incorrectly as far as the data type goes.

I am assuming that -before the export- I have to specify that this particular column should stay of type int64. How do i do this?

This is my code so far:

```
  #Save File
df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/test.csv')
  #Download File
https://dbc-xxx.cloud.databricks.com/test.csv
```

As mentioned, when downloading it, the one column changed from int64 to float64 causing issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `toPandas()` first (very slow) and calling `to_csv` on the pandas DataFrame. The problem is likely that you have `null` values in your spark DataFrame which get converted to `nan` (`numpy.nan` is a float). Nevertheless, you're probably better off using `df.write.csv()` on the Spark side but that's a different story.

Comment: So would your code suggestion solve the issue or do you just suggest a better code quality? In any case, what needs to happen for this to work? Please advise.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or an idea of what your ultimate goal is. [You can't have an integer column in a pandas DataFrame that also contains nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int). What issues is the float64 column causing? Are you okay with dropping nans? What do you mean by "working"?