# How to convert a column with missing value to integer type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, integer

I want to convert a column to integer but the problem is that the column contains a missing value. The column converts to float fine, but cant convert to integer.

Sample code:

```
d2 = {'location': ['NY', 'NY', 'PA', 'NY', 'PA', 'PA', 'NY'], 'dep_name': ['hr', 'mk', 'fin', 'fin', 'hr', 'fin', 'fin'], 'Duration_of_Employment' : [10, 5, 9, 8, 2, 4, 7], 'Salary' : [50000, 86000,25000, 73000, 28000, 60000, 40000], 'Days_Since_Last_Promotion': ['61', '35', '25', '98', 'NaN', '45', '22']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)

df2['xy']  = df2['Days_Since_Last_Promotion'].astype(float)
df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'] = df2['xy'] // 30
```

Now 'Months_Since_Last_Promotion'  is float type. But when I try to convert it to integer I get the following error.

```
df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'] = df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'].astype(int)
```

> ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

From the error, I figured its due to the missing value Nan and tried this work around .But it didnt work and 'Months_Since_Last_Promotion' is still showing as float64.

```
df2.loc[df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'].notnull(), 'Months_Since_Last_Promotion'] = df2.loc[df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'].notnull(), 'Months_Since_Last_Promotion'].astype(int)
```

> Note: I cant use fillna to replace the NaN. The goal is to keep the column as integer.

Comment: not sure why you can't use the fillna, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Pandas column containing NaNs to dtype \`int\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int)

Comment: the requirement is such that we dont want 0 or -1 or sth like that in place of NaN. But I guess in worst case I will take that path

Answer (score 3):

Numeric columns containing `NaN` values are stored as floats by default (even if all other numbers are integers) - this is because of typecasting restrictions in pandas. What this means is that if you want to retain the `NaN` as is without filling the missing value, casting the column to an integer may not be possible (to the best of my knowledge). Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> "While pandas supports storing arrays of integer and boolean type,
>   these types are not capable of storing missing data. Until we can
>   switch to using a native NA type in NumPy, we’ve established some
>   “casting rules”. When a reindexing operation introduces missing data,
>   the Series will be cast according to the rules introduced in the table
>   below."

Please refer to:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#missing-data-casting-rules-and-indexing

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way for that:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

in your case:

```
df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'] = pd.array(df2['Months_Since_Last_Promotion'], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
```

However, it is important to note that other softwares may not be able to recognize this column as an `int` column. I think this have something to do with `NaN` being a `float` in python.