# Convert data type of a column containing nan, hyphen and comma in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Now, I have a column where I have values are as below:

Sample data for reference:

[image]

Now, i want to convert the column a to a numeric format using below code:

```
df[['A']] = df[['A']].astype(int)
```

and it gives me an error.
The problem is I have all three (nan, hyphen and comma) all in one column and need to address them together.
Is there any better way to convert these without replacing (nan to -1) and things like that?

Comment: Please consider posting data as text, not as image. This will increase your chance of getting high quality answer to your question.

Comment: you cannot covert a number with comma into a numeric format, you have to relieve comma. Also, if there are `NaN` (also assuming `-` to be converted to `NaN`) then overall type can be made to `float64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameters `thousands` and `na_values`, but converting to integers is not possible with missing values, because now at least one `NaN` value cast column to `float`s, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290084/2901002). So possible solution is replace them to int, e.g. `-1` and then cast to integer:

*Notice - In new version of pandas (0.24.0, coming soon) pandas has gained the ability to hold integer dtypes with missing values, [Nullable Integer Data Type](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/integer_na.html#integer-na).*

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u'''A
2254
"1,234"
"3,385"
nan
-
-
nan'''
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), 
                 encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
                 thousands=',', 
                 na_values='-')

print (df)
        A
0  2254.0
1  1234.0
2  3385.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
```

---

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(-1).astype(int)
print (df)
      A
0  2254
1  1234
2  3385
3    -1
4    -1
5    -1
6    -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should do `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and `str.replace`:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'].str.replace(',',''),errors='coerce')
```

And now:

```
print(df['A'])
```

Is:

```
0    2254.0
1    1234.0
2    3385.0
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```