# Pandas - how to coerce only empty string values in dataframe column to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With data like below

```
colVals = [['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   185', '892', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '892', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '    73', '892', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '892', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    73', '892', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.708', '268', '4', '28', '-67.60', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2', '13.128', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '    57', '892', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   201', '892', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    25', '892', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '893', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '893', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '893', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.726', '268', '4', '', '-67.80', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '12.902', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.728', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '   185', '894', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.728', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   185', '894', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   217', '894', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '894', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '894', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '894', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '895', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '895', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '895', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.746', '268', '4', '', '-67.82', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.243', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '28', '', '13', '20', '2', '3', '   185', '896', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '896', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '', '', '', '30', '', '3', '   217', '896', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '896', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '896', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '896', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '896', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   217', '897', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '30', '', '3', '   217', '897', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '897', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '897', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.766', '268', '4', '', '-67.13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.685', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.768', '', '', '28', '', '12', '20', '2', '3', '   185', '898', '3', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.768', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '898', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '898', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '898', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '898', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    41', '899', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '899', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.786', '268', '4', '', '-67.66', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.683', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '28', '', '13', '18', '2', '3', '   185', '900', '0', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '900', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '900', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '    41', '900', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '900', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '900', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    89', '900', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '900', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '900', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '900', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.806', '268', '4', '', '-67.50', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.023', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '   185', '902', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   185', '902', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '902', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '902', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '902', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '902', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    89', '902', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   121', '902', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '902', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '902', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    73', '902', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '     9', '902', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '902', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '902', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '902', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '903', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '   105', '903', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    41', '903', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '     9', '903', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   105', '903', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   121', '903', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '903', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.826', '268', '4', '', '-67.51', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.370', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '28', '', '12', '18', '2', '3', '   185', '904', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '904', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '904', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '904', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '904', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '904', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '904', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   169', '904', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '904', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '904', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.846', '268', '4', '', '-67.01', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.227', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '28', '', '13', '19', '2', '3', '    57', '906', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '    41', '906', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '    73', '906', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '906', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '906', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '     9', '906', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   121', '906', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    57', '906', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '906', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '906', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '906', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '906', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '907', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '     9', '907', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    57', '907', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   153', '907', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    57', '907', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '907', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '908', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '908', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '     9', '908', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '    73', '908', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.868', '268', '4', '28', '-66.79', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2', '13.969', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '908', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '908', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '908', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '908', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '     9', '908', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   121', '908', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '908', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '908', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '908', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '    73', '909', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '909', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '909', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '909', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.886', '268', '4', '', '-67.48', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.857', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '   185', '910', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '910', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '     9', '910', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '910', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '910', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '910', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '910', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    73', '910', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '910', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '910', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '910', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-10.0', '  8', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 13.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 17.0', ' 48', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  0', ' 12', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 24', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  8', ' 12', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -6.0', '  4', ' 24', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -4.0', '  8', ' 32', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'SS_0', '  1.0', '  0', '216', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 16.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -4.0', '  8', ' 32', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -3.0', ' 12', ' 44', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 15.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-11.0', '  0', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-11.0', '  0', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -8.0', '  8', ' 16', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-15.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'SS_0', ' -1.0', '  0', '216', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  0', ' 16', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 14.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-15.0', ' 12', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  8', ' 24', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  6.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-16.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -6.0', '  8', ' 44', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -6.0', '  0', ' 44', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  7.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-16.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-17.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', '  4', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 14.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-16.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', '  0', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '911', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '911', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   105', '911', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    25', '911', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '911', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '911', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   153', '911', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   137', '911', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.906', '268', '4', '', '-67.79', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.234', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '28', '', '13', '18', '2', '3', '    57', '912', '0', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '912', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '912', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   137', '912', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   169', '912', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.923', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '913', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.923', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '913', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
colNames = ['Time', 'Col01', 'Col02', 'Col03', 'Col04', 'Col05', 'Col06', 'Col07', 'Col08', 'Col09', 'Col10', 'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14', 'Col15', 'Col16', 'Col17', 'Col18', 'Col19', 'Col20']
```

I'm creating a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(colVals, columns=colNames)
```

This gives all the columns as object (Strings)

```
df.dtypes
Out[28]: 
Time     object
Col01    object
Col02    object
Col03    object
Col04    object
Col05    object
Col06    object
Col07    object
Col08    object
Col09    object
Col10    object
Col11    object
Col12    object
Col13    object
Col14    object
Col15    object
Col15    object
Col16    object
Col17    object
Col18    object
Col19    object
dtype: object
```

I want to convert the columns as appropiate data types as floats, int and strings. For example `Col01` should be int, `Col04` should be float and `Col15` should be string.

using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029781/3206440) -

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
def func(x):
    a = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
    try:
        return a.astype('Int64')
    except:
        return a

df1 = df.apply(func)
```

This works for floats and int type columns, but it also converts all strings to `NaN`. The desired results is that only null strings `''` shall be converted to `NaN`. How to go about this?

Comment: You can use `.fillna('')`

Comment: Your function is working fine when i run it. I get `NAN` only where there is no value, the values are retained as is for the rest.

Comment: Per numpy, if you have a NaN, it is a float (not an int).  You cannot mix integers with NaNs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan

Comment: @Alexander with pandas 0.24+, you can have `int` type for a col even if 'NaN` is present. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type

Comment: @user3206440 I thought this may have changed at some point. Thanks for the reminder and for the version where the switch occurred.

Comment: please tell me if my answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need convert to floats first and then to `Int64`:

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
df1 = df.mask(df.eq(''))

def func(x):
    try:
        return x.astype('float').astype('Int64') #pd 0.24+ 
    except:
        try:
            return x.astype('float')
        except:
            return x
df2 = df1.apply(func)
```

---

```
print (df2.dtypes)
Col01      Int64
Col02      Int64
Col03      Int64
Col04    float64
Col05      Int64
Col06      Int64
Col07      Int64
Col08      Int64
Col09      Int64
Col10      Int64
Col11      Int64
Col12      Int64
Col13    float64
Col14      Int64
Col15     object
Col16      Int64
Col17      Int64
Col18      Int64
Col19      Int64
Col20      Int64
dtype: object
```

You can investigate unique values - `float`s are returned only because at least 1 non `NaN`s floats (`Col04`, `Col13`) and object only if at least 1 non `NaN` string value (`Col15`):

```
print (df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique())))
   Col01 Col02 Col03   Col04 Col05 Col06 Col07 Col08   Col09 Col10 Col11  \
0    NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN    21   NaN     3     217   891    12   
1    268     4    28  -67.60    13    18     2   NaN     185   892    13   
2    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.80    12    17   NaN   NaN      73   NaN    15   
3    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.82   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   893    16   
4    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.13   NaN    31   NaN   NaN      57   894    17   
5    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.66   NaN    20   NaN   NaN     201   895    18   
6    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.50   NaN    30   NaN   NaN      25   896     0   
7    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.51   NaN    16   NaN   NaN      41   897     1   
8    NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.01   NaN    19   NaN   NaN     105   898     5   
9    NaN   NaN   NaN  -66.79   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN      89   899     6   
10   NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.48   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     121   900     7   
11   NaN   NaN   NaN  -67.79   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       9   902   NaN   
12   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     169   903    10   
13   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     153   904    11   
14   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     137   906     2   
15   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   907     3   
16   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   908     8   
17   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   909   NaN   
18   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   910   NaN   
19   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   911   NaN   
20   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   912   NaN   
21   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   913   NaN   
22   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   
23   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   
24   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   
25   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   
26   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   

   Col12   Col13 Col14 Col15  Col16 Col17 Col18 Col19 Col20  
0    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
1      2  13.128     0   PSH  -10.0     8     8     0   NaN  
2      1  12.902    13   PCH   13.0    48     1   NaN   NaN  
3    NaN  13.243   NaN  SS_0  -13.0    20     4   NaN   NaN  
4    NaN  13.685   NaN   NaN   17.0     0    12   NaN   NaN  
5    NaN  13.683   NaN   NaN   -9.0    24    24   NaN   NaN  
6    NaN  14.023   NaN   NaN   12.0     4    32   NaN   NaN  
7    NaN  14.370   NaN   NaN   -6.0    12   216   NaN   NaN  
8    NaN  14.227   NaN   NaN   -4.0    16     5   NaN   NaN  
9    NaN  13.969   NaN   NaN   11.0   NaN    44   NaN   NaN  
10   NaN  13.857   NaN   NaN    1.0   NaN    16   NaN   NaN  
11   NaN  14.234   NaN   NaN   16.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
12   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   -3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
13   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    9.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
14   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
15   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  -14.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
16   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   15.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
17   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
18   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  -11.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
19   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   -8.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
20   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  -15.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
21   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   -1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
22   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN   14.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
23   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    6.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
24   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  -16.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
25   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN    7.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
26   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN  -17.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the function to:

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return x.astype('Int64')
    except:
        try:
            return x.astype('float')
        except:
            return x
```

Comment: shouldn't this be like `x.astype('Int64')`. Also all the types are of `object`

Comment: @user3206440 1) You are right. I've copy pasted it without noticing `x` changed to `a` in the part I've passed. Edited it. 2) I didn't understand. If it won't succeed converting to `int` or `float` than it'll return `object` like he wanted.

Comment: `df1.dtypes
Out[51]: 
Col01    object
Col02    object
Col03    object
Col04    object
Col05    object
Col06    object
Col07    object
Col08    object
Col09    object
Col10    object
Col11    object
Col12    object
Col13    object
Col14    object
Col15    object
Col16    object
Col17    object
Col18    object
Col19    object
Col20    object
dtype: object`

Comment: guess this is because all columns have some empty strings in it and hence end up in the last `except` block

Comment: @user3206440 If it's always empty string `''`, you can try to add `x = x.astype(str).str.replace('',np.nan)` before the first `try`

Comment: `TypeError: ('repl must be a string or callable', 'occurred at index Col01')`

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the values `​​''` of the original data frame using [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html). And use this data frame to replace the `NaN` values ​​after applying the function (over the original data frame **df**) using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
def func(x):
    a = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')
    try:
        return a.astype('Int64')
    except:
        return a
df1 = df.apply(func,axis=1).fillna(df.mask(df.eq('')))
```

**Col15 df output:**

```
df['Col15'].values

array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH',
       'PSH', 'PCH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'SS_0',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH',
       'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'SS_0', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH',
       'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      dtype=object)
```

**Col15 df1 output:**

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'SS_0', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH',
       'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'SS_0', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH',
       'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH',
       'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', 'PSH', 'PCH', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan], dtype=object)
```

Comment: The problem with the solution is that with the step `a = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')` in `func` all non numeric characters are converted to `NaN`. Eg. just try `df.appy(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: I think algorithmic-ally, first step should be to fill `NaN` where value == '' . Then convert to int, else float else retain original - see below.

Answer (score 0):

```
colVals = [['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '891', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   185', '892', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '892', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '    73', '892', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '892', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    73', '892', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.708', '268', '4', '28', '-67.60', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2', '13.128', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '    57', '892', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   201', '892', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    25', '892', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '893', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '893', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '893', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.726', '268', '4', '', '-67.80', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '12.902', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.728', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '   185', '894', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.728', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   185', '894', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   217', '894', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '894', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '894', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '894', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '895', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '895', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '895', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.746', '268', '4', '', '-67.82', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.243', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '28', '', '13', '20', '2', '3', '   185', '896', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '896', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '', '', '', '30', '', '3', '   217', '896', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '896', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '896', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '896', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '896', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   217', '897', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '30', '', '3', '   217', '897', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '897', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '897', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.766', '268', '4', '', '-67.13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.685', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.768', '', '', '28', '', '12', '20', '2', '3', '   185', '898', '3', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.768', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '898', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '898', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '898', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '898', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    41', '899', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '899', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '899', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.786', '268', '4', '', '-67.66', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.683', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '28', '', '13', '18', '2', '3', '   185', '900', '0', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '900', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '900', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '    41', '900', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '900', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '900', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    89', '900', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '900', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '900', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '900', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.806', '268', '4', '', '-67.50', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.023', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '   185', '902', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '   185', '902', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '902', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '902', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '902', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '902', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    89', '902', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   121', '902', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '902', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '902', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    73', '902', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '     9', '902', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '902', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '902', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '902', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '903', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '   105', '903', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    41', '903', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '     9', '903', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   105', '903', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '903', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   121', '903', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '903', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.826', '268', '4', '', '-67.51', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.370', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '28', '', '12', '18', '2', '3', '   185', '904', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '904', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '904', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '904', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '904', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '904', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '904', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   169', '904', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '904', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '904', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.846', '268', '4', '', '-67.01', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.227', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '28', '', '13', '19', '2', '3', '    57', '906', '1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '    41', '906', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '    73', '906', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '906', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '   217', '906', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '     9', '906', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   121', '906', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    57', '906', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '906', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '906', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '906', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '906', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '907', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '     9', '907', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    57', '907', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   153', '907', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   217', '907', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    57', '907', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '907', '18', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   185', '908', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   185', '908', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '     9', '908', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '    73', '908', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.868', '268', '4', '28', '-66.79', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2', '13.969', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '   105', '908', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '    25', '908', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '908', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '908', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '     9', '908', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   121', '908', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '908', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '908', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '908', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '    73', '909', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '909', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '909', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '909', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.886', '268', '4', '', '-67.48', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '13.857', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '   185', '910', '0', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '910', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '     9', '910', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '910', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '910', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '910', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '910', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    73', '910', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '910', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '910', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '910', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-10.0', '  8', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 13.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 17.0', ' 48', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  0', ' 12', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 24', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  8', ' 12', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -6.0', '  4', ' 24', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -4.0', '  8', ' 32', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'SS_0', '  1.0', '  0', '216', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 16.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -4.0', '  8', ' 32', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -3.0', ' 12', ' 44', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 12.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 15.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-11.0', '  0', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-11.0', '  0', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 11.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -8.0', '  8', ' 16', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-15.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'SS_0', ' -1.0', '  0', '216', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  0', ' 16', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 14.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-15.0', ' 12', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -9.0', '  8', ' 24', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  6.0', '  0', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-16.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -6.0', '  8', ' 44', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', ' -6.0', '  0', ' 44', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  7.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-16.0', ' 16', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-17.0', ' 20', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  8.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-14.0', '  4', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 14.0', ' 48', '  5', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-16.0', '  0', '  4', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', '  9.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '  0', 'PSH', '-13.0', '  0', '  8', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.893', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' 13', 'PCH', ' 10.0', ' 48', '  1', '  0', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '911', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   217', '911', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   105', '911', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    25', '911', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '   217', '911', '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '911', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   153', '911', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '911', '16', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   137', '911', '17', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.906', '268', '4', '', '-67.79', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '14.234', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '28', '', '13', '18', '2', '3', '    57', '912', '0', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   185', '912', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    57', '912', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   137', '912', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '   169', '912', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.923', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '   217', '913', '11', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.923', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '    89', '913', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
colNames = ['Time', 'Col01', 'Col02', 'Col03', 'Col04', 'Col05', 'Col06', 'Col07', 'Col08', 'Col09', 'Col10', 'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14', 'Col15', 'Col16', 'Col17', 'Col18', 'Col19', 'Col20']
df = pd.DataFrame(colVals, columns=colNames)
```

Keep the time col as index

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
```

Fill in `''` with `NaN`

```
df1 = df.mask(df.eq(''))
```

Function to convert to int else float else string

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return x.astype('Int64') #pd 0.24+ 
    except:
        try:
            return x.astype('float')
        except:
            return x
df2 = df1.apply(func)
```

The problem with this is that int looking values are also

```
df2.dtypes
Col01    float64
Col02    float64
Col03    float64
Col04    float64
Col05    float64
Col06    float64
Col07    float64
Col08    float64
Col09    float64
Col10    float64
Col11    float64
Col12    float64
Col13    float64
Col14    float64
Col15     object
Col16    float64
Col17    float64
Col18    float64
Col19    float64
Col20      Int64
dtype: object
```

It seems the `Int64` conversion is failing on all columns except `Col20` where all values are `NaN`

To check this on `Col01`

```
df1["Col01"].unique()
Out[37]: array([nan, '268'], dtype=object)
```

Applying `Int64` conversion only on `Col01`

```
dtype_dict = {'Col01': 'Int64'}
df1.astype(dtype_dict)
```

This throws error `TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype`

Looking at pandas version

```
pd.__version__
Out[38]: '0.25.1'
```

Why is the `Int64` conversion failing here. According to [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type), this should have worked