# Pandas: ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 2

Tags: python, pandas

I get value errors when trying to read in the csv file to my datatype.
I need to be sure that it works and that every line is read in and is correct.

Errors are for example:

```
Pandas: ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 2
```

I am trying to cast to integer in Pandas Python library, but there is a value.

However, the csv file that I read in seems to have some erroneous entries, as it consists of manually entered test results.

I read in using this command:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", names=pandasframe_names, dtype=pandasframe_datatypes, skiprows=1)
```

names is A, B, C, D and E and is defined correctly.

If there is an erroneous entry, I need a way of handling this without losing the full row.

So here is my case:
I have a pandas dataframe that reads in a csv table with 5 columns with the
headers A, B, C, D, E. I skip row one with the parameter skiprows=1

```
pandas_datatypes={'A': pd.np.int64, 'B':pd.np.int64, 'C':pd.np.float64, 'D':object, 'E':object}
```

My row has 5 column and the first 2 are int64 and the 3rd is float64 and the next 2 are object (e.g. string)

Those are equivalent to my dtype when I read it in. Meaning `dtype=pandas_datatypes`

Now I have entries like so:

```
entry 1: 5; 5; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher (correct)
entry 2: 8; 7.0; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher (incorrect, as second is float instead of int)
entry 3: NA; 5; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher (incorrect, as first value has entered NA as is missing)
entry 4: none; 5; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher (incorrect, as first value has entered none as is missing)
entry 5: 8; 5; 2; pedagogy; teacher (incorrect, as third is int instead of float)
```

How do I best handle this and what do I have to add to make this work for sure?
In case that there is one incorrect entry, I don't want to lose the full line. Should I enter NULL? But then I would need to flag this for someone to manually look at it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas column containing NaNs to dtype \`int\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int)

Answer (score 25):

Pandas now has extension types, for which integer support NA values. You will get pd.NA in those fields.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes

Use Pandas Int64 type, you'll be fine!

```
pandas_datatypes={'A': 'Int64', 'B': 'Int64', 'C':pd.np.float64, 'D':object, 'E':object}
```

Just tested it with pandas 1.3.5, works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have incomplete/corrupt data (very common!), you can't enforce dtypes from the outset. You have to first import it as is:

Given `file1.csv`:

```
5; 5; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher
8; 7.0; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher
NA; 5; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher
none; 5; 2.2; pedagogy; teacher
8; 5; 2; pedagogy; teacher
```

We can read it as

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=';', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

We then coerce A, B and C to numeric, forcing `NaN` wherever there is text.

```
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

You then have the C as a float col. Making A and B into ints is a bit trickier, since they have `NaN` values ([a known Pandas issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int)).

If you have 0.24 or higher, you can do:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Otherwise you can either fill the `NaN`s in some way, or live with the floats.

Comment: How do I deal with forcing the number types into strings?

Comment: my datamodel has type varchar in sqllite, so maybe string would be wrong. what is the best way to force this on import to varchar?

Comment: columns D and E have type varchar in my datamodel. I use sqlalchemy ORM. When I import, the data model I get in SQLLite TEXT. But I need varchar. Also both the pd.Int64Dtype() and pd.Int32Dtype() yield BIGINT in SQLLite, but I need an INTEGER datatype on import.

Comment: D and E are object type, which should be VARCHAR in SQL. As for the other issue, I don't know if it can be helped, maybe you can convert it in SQL after you add it to the DB?

Comment: D and E become TEXT in SQL not varchar, any suggestion on how to convert this?

Comment: See [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/converting-text-columns-to-varcharmax) but I think best to make this a new question