# convert pandas dataframe datatypes from float64 into int64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oracle11g, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read CSV file by using python pandas, in the resultant dataframe one column is returned as float64 datatype instead of int64. But I could see most of the values are numbers and some of them are null values in the existing CSV file

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)

dh.head(3)

Name State  Id
SFO  CA     123.0
JFK  NY     152.0
CHG  IL     NaN
ABC  AZ     NaN

df.dypes

Name Object
State Object
Id float64
```

I tried convert Id column into Int64 to upload data into oracle table

```
df['Id'] = df['Id'].astype('int64')
```

Error : Cannot convert NA to integer

Is there any approach to convert Id column into int64 ? I appreciate your response.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas column containing NaNs to dtype \`int\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int)

Answer (score 1):

In **Python 3.7.6** and **pandas 1.0.3** you can do:

```
df['Id'] = df['Id'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Name     object
State    object
Id        Int64

State    Id
0  SFO    CA   123
1  JFK    NY   152
2  CHG    IL  <NA>
3  ABC    AZ  <NA>
```

Comment: I have tried, but no luck.Its giving error
AttributeError: Module 'pandas' has no attribute 'pd.Int64Dtype()'

Comment: What is your python and pandas version?

Comment: python - 3.6 and pandas - 0.19.2

Comment: @Naresh I added my Python and pandas version to my answer. Good luck!

Comment: @Naresh You -at least- will have to upgrade to pandas 0.24.2 for this to work https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.2.html