# Pandas to_sql ignoring dtype when column contains null values

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dtype, pandas-to-sql

First SO Question. I hope this is descriptive enough.

Pandas 0.25, Oracle 11g

I have a dataframe read from a csv.  It contains a mix of numeric, string and date data.

I force data types within the dataframe using `.astype(str)`, `.astype(int)` and `.to_datetime`.

I then create a dtype dictionary to select the data types I want.

When there are some nulls in the numeric columns `types.NUMBER` and `types.INTEGER` creates a `FLOAT` in the Oracle table.  It should be `NUMBER(38,0)`, especially if I use `types.INTEGER`. The key column that is defined as  `types.NUMBER` and contains all non-null integers is created as a `NUMBER(38,0)` as expected.

When there are columns with all nulls, but have had `.astype(str)` applied and dtype of `types.VARCHAR(300)` the columns are also created as `FLOAT` in Oracle.

I need to use `if_exists='append'` in to_sql as the table collects history, so I can't wait for the VARCHAR columns to recieve data.  Though I have been using `if_exists='replace` during testing to ensure the table is dropped and recreated.

Is there a way to resolve these issues, caused by nulls in the data, resulting in the datatype selection being incorrect?   I shouldn't need to use a blank (ie '') in the strings and 0 for integers, I need nulls to come through as nulls.

Nulls in date columns, even when the entire column is null values works, and creates a `DATE` in Oracle as requested.

EDIT:  String to VARCHAR Issue was actually an issue with a trapped and incorrectly handled exception.

Numbers were still an issue that had to be handled separately I will add an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the numeric fields with some null and some non-null values was due to Pandas using NaN for null and numpy treating NaN as float.

`.astype(int)` doesn't handle NaN's and actually raises an exception due to the NaNs (which a try block had caught and handled incorrectly in my case).

The solution is: `df['pref1'] = df['pref1'].astype('Int64')`

The 'Int64' needs the capitalised 'I'. `.astype('int64')` also doesn't work.

[This answer was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194908/7140431)