# Differencing Time Series & Create Stationary Time Series - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to difference time series to make it stationary. However it is not guaranteed that by taking first lag would make time series stationary. Generate an example Pandas dataframe as below

```
test = {'A':[10,15,19,24,23]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

by using `diff()` method we can take first lag as expected but if I attempt `diff(2)` i.e. if I want to use a lag period of 2 I am not getting results as expected.

**Expected Output**

```
+----+-------+-------+
| A  | Lag 1 | Lag 2 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 10 | NA    | NA    |
| 15 | 5     | NA    |
| 19 | 4     |-1     |
| 24 | 5     | 1     |
| 23 |-1     |-6     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

**Resulting Output**

```
+----------------+
|  A  lag1  lag2 |
+----------------+
| 10   NaN   NaN |
| 15   5.0   NaN |
| 19   4.0   9.0 |
| 24   5.0   9.0 |
| 23  -1.0   4.0 |
+----------------+
```

The above output was generated using `test_df['lag2'] = test_df['A'].diff(2)`.
How can I obtain the expected output and regenerate the actual time series by only using the `Lag 2` time series?

**Edit 1**
This question does not pertains to any data type conversion or NaNs and is incorrectly marked as duplicate. The expected output is clearly mentioned and the scope of question is completely different from one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int).

**Edit 2**
To work on more number of samples following dummy data frame can be used.

```
test = np.random.randint(100, size=500)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['A'])
```

**Edit 3**
In order to explain the expected output more please consider the expected output below.

```
+----+-------+-------+
| A  | Lag 1 | Lag 2 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 10 | NA    | NA    |
| 15 | 5     | NA    |
| 19 | 4     | -1    |
| 24 | 5     | 1     |
| 23 | -1    | -6    |
| 50 | 27    | 28    |
| 34 | -16   | -43   |
| 56 | 22    | 38    |
| 33 | -23   | -45   |
| 26 | -7    | 16    |
| 45 | 19    | 26    |
+----+-------+-------+

test = {'A': [10,15,19,24,23,50,34,56,33,26,45]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

`Lag 1` of this column can be created using
`test_df['lag1'] = test_df['A'].diff()`. But to create `lag 2` I need to do `test_df['lag2'] = test_df['A'].diff().diff()`. This solution won't work in case where I've to take 365 lags. Hence I need a solution takes lag of original series `A` and then recursively takes lag of `lag1` to generate `lag2` and so on and so forth.

Once we've created lagged term `lag2` how can we retrieve the original series back from it?

Comment: So you need `test_df['lag2'] = test_df['A'].diff().diff()` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes but this solution does not helps if I've to do it for 365 days instead of 2 days. Also I've asked in question how to revert back from 2 days lagged series to original series if values for original series is known.

Comment: Ok, is possible add some `time series` to sample?

Comment: @jezrael the question I've asked is completely different and is not a duplicate. I never asked about any data conversion issues or NaNs in my question. Would you mind explaining how this question has been already answered.

Comment: Reopened, sorry.

Comment: @jezrael random data of 365 samples can be generated I've made an edit to incorporate more data points to dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff(2)` will give you the difference between a<sub>n</sub> and a<sub>n-2</sub>. What you want is the difference between items **of the diff-ed column**. Trivial mathematics show that it will be a<sub>n</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub> - 2 * a<sub>n-1</sub>. That is enough to explain why you do not get the expected result.

What you want is to *iterate* `diff()`:

```
df['Lag 1'] = df['A'].diff()
df['Lag 2'] = df['A'].diff().diff()
```

With `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,15,19,24,23,50,34,56,33,26,45]}`, it gives as expected:

```
     A  Lag 1  Lag 2
0   10    NaN    NaN
1   15    5.0    NaN
2   19    4.0   -1.0
3   24    5.0    1.0
4   23   -1.0   -6.0
5   50   27.0   28.0
6   34  -16.0  -43.0
7   56   22.0   38.0
8   33  -23.0  -45.0
9   26   -7.0   16.0
10  45   19.0   26.0
```

---

The little maths above, suggest that Lag 365 will use the 365 previous values with the binomial coefficients C<sub>365</sub><sup>i</sup>. So IMHO it is simpler to do:

```
s = df['A']
for i in range(365): s = s.diff()
df['Lag 365'] = s
```

If you do not want to keep the intermediary Lag i columns.

---

You can retrieve the initial values from a diff-ed column provided you also have the first value with cumsum: `df['Lag 1'].fillna(df.iloc[0,0]).cumsum()` gives back `df['A']`. So to be able to restore the initial values from a n-diff-ed column, I would use a slight variation of `diff` to keep the initial value instead of the initial NaN:

```
def difx(s):
    return s.diff().combine_first(s)
```

Then to process the 4th diff, I would use

```
s = df['A']
for i in range(4): s = difx(s)
s['Lag 4'] = s
```

it gives:

```
0      10.0
1     -25.0
2      19.0
3      -2.0
4      -9.0
5      41.0
6    -105.0
7     152.0
8    -164.0
9     144.0
10    -51.0
```

We can now retrieve the initial values with

```
s = df['Lag 4']
for i in range(4): s = s.cumsum()
```

We get back as expected the initial values:

```
0     10.0
1     15.0
2     19.0
3     24.0
4     23.0
5     50.0
6     34.0
7     56.0
8     33.0
9     26.0
10    45.0
```

If your Series is long enough, you can do the same for Lag 365 just replacing the `4` in my examples with 365...

Comment: are you suggesting if I need to take `Lag 365`  I need to repeat `.diff()` 365 times?

Comment: I understand that `Lag 365` will require 365 previous values. My question is on how to code it such that I do not have to write `diff()` 365 times which is not possible.