# Truncate decimal numbers in string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, truncate

A weird thing - i have a dataframe, lets call it ID.
While importing xlsx source file, I do .astype({"ID_1": str, "ID_2": str})

Yet, for example instead of 10300 I get 10300.0.
Moreover, then I get string "nan" as well.

In order to fix both issues I did this rubbish:

```
my_df['ID_1'].replace(['None', 'nan'], np.nan, inplace=True)
my_df[my_df['ID_1'].notnull()].ID_1.astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)
```

As a result I still have these 10300.0
Any thoughts how to fix these? I could keep it as float while importing data, instead of .astype, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Pandas has int-types that allow for missing values: Try `.astype({"ID_1": "Int64", "ID_2": "Int64"})` for example. (Have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `int` cannot represent `NaN` value, so pandas converts the column to `float`.

It is a common pitfall, as the presence of additional rows with missing data can change the result of a given row.

You can however pick a specific pandas type to indicate that it is an integer with missing values, see [Convert Pandas column containing NaNs to dtype `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int), especially the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html