# How to change format of floar values in column with also NaN values in Pandas Data Frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, floating

I have Pandas DataFrame in Python like below:

```
col
-------
7.0
2.0
NaN
...
```

**"col1" is in float data type** but I would like to convert displaying of floar values in this column from for example 7.0 to 7. I can not simply change date type to int because I have also "NaN" values in col1.

So as a result I need something like below:

```
col
-------
7
2
NaN
...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: you actually can. Pandas introduces Nullable Integer Data Types which allows integers to coexist with NaNs. So you should be good with `.astype('Int32')`

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int) your answer?

Comment: Formats belong to *formatting* and *displaying* a dataframe, not how it is stored. I don't quite understand the question. Do you want to display the dataframe with a specific format? That can be done. Store data in a dataframe "with specific float precision"? (Can't be done.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html?highlight=convert_dtypes#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes) to perform an automatic conversion:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes('col')
```

For all columns:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
    col
0     7
1     2
2  <NA>
```

After conversion:

```
df.dtypes

col    Int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: What is <NA> ? if I try to do: df[df["col"] == "<NA>"] ot df[df["col"] == np.nan] I do not have any results ? :/

Comment: You should never use direct comparison with NAs, use `df[df["col"].isna()]`. NB. This is **not** a string, but the `pd.NA` object.

Comment: Ok thank you, I gave best answer! Could you return yo my previous question ?