# pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting column in csv with prices to diferent value(currency change) with Pandas.
I get this error an i suspect it is due to length of the column which is 35000 rows.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"products.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Price"])
df["Price"] = df["Price"].astype(int)


def divide_by_7_5(numbers):
    return [number / 7.5 for number in numbers]


result = divide_by_7_5(df)
print(result)
```

Error----->. pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

I try to add:

```
low_memory=False
```

i didn't give positive result.

Comment: You probably have empty cells, try adding `df = df.fillna(0)`

Comment: OP should be careful doing that since empty cells will be filled with zero.

Comment: The question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code is doing what you expect.

When looping over a dataframe, you loop over the **column names**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, np.nan, np.inf], 'col2': [1, 2, 3]})

def divide_by_7_5(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        print(number)

divide_by_7_5(df)
```

Output:

```
col1
col2
```

If you just want to divide by 7.5, a simple `numbers / 7.5` is sufficient, no need to handle `NaN` or `Inf` in a special way:

```
def divide_by_7_5(numbers):
    return numbers / 7.5

result = divide_by_7_5(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1      col2
0   0.0  0.133333
1   NaN  0.266667
2   inf  0.400000
```