# why does pandas map function always create a float value

Tags: pandas

I am trying to map some data I get from another function to my Pandas dataframe.
I create a simple dict for the lookup.
For some reason the map function always creates float64 from integers.

So here I create a dictionary for the map function and force the ID to be an int.

```
all_serials = {phone["serial"]:int(phone["id"]) for phone in all_phones}
df["id"] = df["serial"].map(all_serials)
```

But still the "id" field is a float64 afterwards.

I have also tried to use astype function:

```
all_serials = {phone["serial"]:int(phone["id"]) for phone in all_phones}
df["id"] = df["serial"].map(all_serials).astype(int)
```

But then I get "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer" for all the lines with no match(NaN as value).

Comment: a series is of one type (values) and `NaN` can not be int

Comment: But that does not explain why map converts the int to float. It works with strings, but only integers seems to be a problem

Answer (score 0):

As [RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest) stated, Pandas does not, by default, store `NaN` values with `int` values in the same column so it will automatically convert all values to `float`. See [this post about NaN values and ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int).

Take this mapping example:

```
num1 = [1111, 3333, 4444, 7777]
num2 = [1, 3, 4, 7] 
linkage = pd.DataFrame({"num1":num1, "num2":num2})

num1 = [1111, 3333, 5555, 8888]
df = pd.DataFrame({"num1":num1})

mapper = linkage.set_index('num1')['num2']
df['num2'] = df.num1.map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
    num1    num2
0   1111    1.0
1   3333    3.0
2   5555    NaN
3   8888    NaN
```

Because `5555` and `8888` in `df` are not found in `linkage`, the `map` function maps `NaN` to those rows. As soon as `NaN` is placed in the column, the rest of the column is converted to `float` as is the default nature of Pandas. You can convert it back to `int` by changing the type of the column to `Int64` whereas trying to convert it to just type `int` will get you the error that you saw above.

```
df.num2 = df.num2.astype('Int64')
```

Output:

```
num1    num2
0   1111    1
1   3333    3
2   5555    <NA>
3   8888    <NA>
```