# Casting a column to string in a dataframe does not remove .0

Tags: python, pandas

I get json from an api. The Python code looks like this:

```
tr_query = transaction_query.get_transaction_query(db_cursor)
r = requests.post(endPoint, json={"query": tr_query}, headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    jsonData = r.json()

    edges = jsonData['data']['transactions']['edges']
    page_info = jsonData['data']['transactions']["pageInfo"]
       
    df_edges = pd.json_normalize(edges)
    df_edges["node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId"] = df_edges["node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId"].astype(str)
    df_edges.rename(columns=column_mapping, inplace=True)
```

The `node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId` is only numbers and the dataframe adds .0 at the end. I've tried to remove it by setting the datatype to `str` but nothing works. How can I remove the .0 at the end?

Comment: Did you mean to convert it to `int` instead of `str`? It's not clear to me why you expect that converting to string will remove `.0`.

Comment: If the number in node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId is "2347234" i want that and not "2347234.0". I don't know why it adds .0 at the end.

Comment: I can't convert it to int because not all node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId has a value

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/convert-pandas-column-containing-nans-to-dtype-int

Comment: This is the solution df_edges["node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId"] = df_edges["node.glDimension.glObject2.dbId"].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. For help with code, it helps to make a [mre]. If I were you, I'd make an example version of `edges` and remove all the code before it. For some specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, if you want more tips, check out [ask]. You can [edit], and while you're there, please add what you mentioned in the comment, "I can't convert it to int ...".

Comment: @Magnus But then they're not numbers anymore... Is that what you want?